# Did I do something wrong with my question?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I just got a question removed, without any comment or explaination.

I'd like some opinions to know whether I did something actually wrong, or if my question *might* have just been hastly judged, due to its content.

*I must say I'm more used to asking/answering programming questions, on SO*

- What I was looking for was clear : a specific unicode character, or say "emote", to use in a text display.
- From my pov, this is Computer software related, and on topic for Superuser.

  *If not, where should I ask this ?  Not on `Tex` or `Writing`, right ?*
- I told why I was needing it, and gave the (unsatisfying) results I found so far
- I made my best to have it well-formatted and readable.

I'll assume the nature of the emote isn't the problem, but then, could you please point me the issue(s) in my question ?

The best I can come up with is it could be too specific.

---

While I'm pretty sure no character is available ATM, I was expecting actual **answer(s)**, with some informations, or circumvention advices.

Or at least, advices to improve my question, if it was *that* bad.

--

*Here lies my defunct question* :
https://superuser.com/questions/1505564/looking-for-an-ass-butt-unicode-character-is-there-just-nothing-available

Answer (score 3):

> I'll assume the nature of the emote isn't the problem, but then, could
>   you please point me the issue(s) in my question?

**I strongly disagree.**  There is a good chance your question was flagged due to the subject matter.  Common sense indicates that there isn't any legitimate use for emoticons that depict a body part or anything that violates a social normality.  **For instance, this is the reason emoticons don't exist, which have been used by hate groups (Nazi, KKK, etc.).**

> Or at least, advices to improve my question, if it was that bad.

Community users are asked not to engage in questions they don't believe are legitimate.  We are asked to flag the question and allow a moderator to handle the situation.  **This is exactly what happen in your case.**

> I just got a question removed, without any comment or explanation.

A reason actually was given: **This question was removed from Super User for reasons of moderation.**

However, a [moderator](https://superuser.com/users/307/random) deleted the question, due to other users choosing to flag the question. Users with enough reputation are able to see which reason the moderator selected when the question was deleted: **This question was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown**

> I told why I was needing it, and gave the (unsatisfying) results I found so far

You did not actually indicate the reason.  However, not indicating the reason you need a specific emoticon, had nothing to do with the reason your question was deleted.

> While I'm pretty sure no character is available ATM, I was expecting actual answer(s), with some information, or circumvention advices.

Every emoticon that exists is documented by the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/standard/standard.html) standard.  If an emoticon does not exist there is a good chance it does not exist.  You did not indicate what OS you were using, in general what emoticons exist on an OS, depends on what versions a specific OS support.

Comment: A bit much to conflate an emoji of a "body part" with Nazis and the KKK I'd have thought.  I agree it was the subject as questions asking for less controversial subjects like  [pacman](https://superuser.com/questions/194195/is-there-a-pac-man-like-character-in-ascii-or-unicode) or [Windows key](https://superuser.com/questions/1247382/is-there-a-unicode-character-for-the-windows-key?rq=1) seem popular.

Comment: @lx07 - Perhaps my examples were over the top, but they were the simplest examples, to explain the reason butt (and other body parts) emojis are not a thing. There are hundreds (or dozens) of flag emojis but the confederate flag isn’t among them.

Answer (score 1):

I closed it because it was, broadly speaking, a shopping question asking us to find a character or group of characters which meet a broad set of requirements. There could be anywhere between 1 and hundreds or thousands of characters (considering diacritics) that could *potentially* be combined to form something with the vaguest resemblance to what you were wanting.

While it may have been about font glyphs it is roughly analogous to to a product recommendation. "Give me a piece of software that fits these requirements." Which is off topic per the help centre.

I didn't delete it, but I was very tempted, as it is basically off topic and there is no real technical reason to need to type an "ass" symbol into any program that will solve or cause an actual problem. Your problem was about *you not finding a symbol or set of symbols*, not a problem that one might cause. It is not a problem *using* computer hardware or software, you just wanted someone else to do the shopping for relevant symbols.

It wasn't really in scope, and had a lot of unnecessary colourful language and symbolism.  At best it could be seen as vulgar and impolite.

Comment: I (IMO clearly) showed I did my best to shop what I could by myself.

If someone knows about a better way than googling or using the search bars of some sites indexing unicode chars, thats the kind of things which could help, and the reason I took the time to write a question.

Yet, I'd probably agree with you on the "lot of unnecessary colorful language" (symbolism was quite necessary to illustrate what I found, right ?).  I tend to like puns and verbosity, and the subject was a slippery invitation to abuse of it, so... I guess we wouldn't put the "golden mean" at the same place.

Comment: @Balmipour - All shopping questions are out of scope here at Super User